# Remote connections into sql08

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Does someone have a link where I can read on how to access my remote server's sql server '08 installation?

**update**

I want to access sql server 2008 from management studio on a remote server.

Remote access is disabled by default!

Answer (score 2):

badbadboy's link would be a good start

1. Enable remote connection in SSMS
2. Check for TCP/IP, Named Pipe enabled in Configuration Manager
3. Check the Firewall

And double check you're connecting to the correct server\instance name, and PORT

Answer (score 0):

Could you please expand your question? 
How do you want to access it? With SQL management studio? Doesn't specifying the computer name work? Are you able to access it locally? Is there anything specific about that it is 2008 SQL?